# How do I config multiple doc_root in PHP?

Tags: php, configuration, nginx

I'm adding a second domain hosted in another folder besides the former one. Is there anyway to add another directory to `doc_root` config? I have tried using comma and space to separate the two path(e.g `doc_root = "/path1 /path2"`) but none of them would work. Do I have to omit this config? I think it's not secure.

(I know I can put them together in one path but it would be a very huge work to rewrite those absolute paths I used in scripts)

Comment: @matt Yes, it is a vhost(in nginx we call them serverblocks) but what does whether it's a virtual host matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this comment on the manual installation page of PHP by chance...

> Bill dot Rook at Gmail dot com 18-Sep-2005 03:09
>
> doc_root =".;c:\inetpub\wwwroot" does seem to work with virtual websites. This
> might be a better option then commenting out the line.

http://php.net/manual/bg/install.windows.manual.php